# Python not printing from list

Tags: python, list

```
from random import randint


person = ["My friend", "My sister", "Joe mama", "Barack Obama"]
speech = ["said", "shouted", "whispered"]
personSecond = ["he", "she"]
expression = ["likes", "hates", "always thinks about"]
ing = ["playing computer games", "dominating the world"]

w = randint(0,3)
x = randint(0,2)
y = randint(0,2)
z = randint(0,3)

print(person[w], speech[x], end = " ")

if w == '0' or w == '3':
    print(personSecond[0], end = " ")
elif w == '1' or w == '2':
    print(personSecond[1], end = " ")

print(expression[y], ing[z])
```

I only get the person, speech, expression and ing output. Python doesn't print strings from personSecond list

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You're comparing strings an numbers with `w == '0'`

Comment: note: please don't use offensive text in your examples. edited out

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare numbers to strings. `w` is a number. `'0'` is a string.

```
if w == 0 or w == 3
```

or

```
if w in (0, 3)
```

or

```
if not w or w == 3
```